# Modification of Real World Haskell program to count number of words and lines using MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, haskell

I'm trying to make some simple modifications to a program from Real World Haskell Chapter 24. Here's some code that counts the number of lines in a file:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count '\n')
                      rdeepseq sum
```

I'm trying to write some code that counts the words in the file. Here's what I came up with:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (length LB.words)
                      rdeepseq sum
```

However, I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `LB.ByteString -> b0'
            with actual type `Int'
In the return type of a call of `length'
Probable cause: `length' is applied to too many arguments
In the second argument of `mapReduce', namely `(length LB.words)'
In the expression:
  mapReduce rdeepseq (length LB.words) rdeepseq sum
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `length` to the result of calling `LB.words`, not to `LB.words` the function. Try `(length . LB.words)`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work. Now I get the error:

Comment: Couldn't match expected type `Int64' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: [Int] -> Int64
        Actual type: [Int] -> Int
    In the fourth argument of `mapReduce', namely `sum'
    In the expression:
        mapReduce rdeepseq (length . LB.words) rdeepseq sum

Comment: Oh wait, it worked when I changed the function to lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int instead of lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! For future reference, it's sometimes useful when facing type errors to delete your own annotations if you think you've got the code right. Sometimes the error is there and sometimes, even more excitingly, the compiler will infer a more general type than you thought you had.